# Automation of the removing azure devops billing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cost-management

I would like to remove the billing of an azure devops organization after it passes a certain threshold so that they don't get overcharged. 
So i have two questions about it. Firstly, is it possible budget scoping on a specific Azure Devops organization at the cost management/billing on Azure Portal? If yes, can i automate the removal of the billing by using azure functions, logic apps or another action type?
I have checked the azure devops cli and rest api but i couldn't find any related action. Also, i couldn't find on cost management the resource group for Azure Devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, is it possible budget scoping on a specific Azure DevOps
>   organization at the cost management/billing on Azure Portal?

Sorry it's not available at present. All the extra paid service such like Azure Pipelines, Azure Artifacts, User licenses are pre-order monthly.

It's also not able to automate removing Azure DevOps billing. If you do not want to use some of them next month, you have to manually cancel assigned license or service.

More details please take a look at our official billing page--[**Pricing for Azure DevOps**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/)